# Html select option display value with empty color div and display value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need the HTML select option display a value with an empty color div and display value.

How do we do that with HTML, JavaScript or jQuery?

I attached a png value, I need it to be like that.

```
<select>

<option value="volvo"><div style="width:10px;height:10px;background-color:red"></div>V</option>

<option value="saab">Saab</option>

<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>

<option value="audi">Audi</option>

</select>
```

This is what I need:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You need to share relevant code ( css html jq )  to create an example of your problem in a local snippet . Also share what you have tried to solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hi mihai T i added code

Comment: the problem is that you have very limited access to edit the `option` tag as many styles like `background-image` are not supported cross-browser. Select,option,radio,checkbox are very browser-dependent . So changing their default styles 99% won't work on every browser

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use select2 library.
https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

No you can't as `<option>` tags cannot contain any other tags. Therefore adding any div or span inside `<option>` tag is not possible.

But you can try https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Answer (score 0):

You could always just colour the entire option like this:

```
<select >
<option style="background-color: lightblue;" value="Saab">Saab</option>
<option style="background-color: lightgreen;" value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option style="background-color: red;" value="Audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Otherwise I'm not too sure you can achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: hi i need an empty colored div with space and then displaytext.